# NextCloud Using Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, nextcloud

I have a case where I have two AWS EC2 instances, and both have the same S3 as primary storage, an RDS as a shared database and an EFS as a shared storage, I have AWS ELB (elastic load balancer) behind those two EC2 instances, and NextCloud server (both of them) open from the browser, and I'm able to create users on them and sync files, and also to connect on both servers using the NextCloud desktop client, but the problem I'm not able connect to the ELB using the NextCloud Client, the client keeps loading then give the message **"connection closed"**

any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

UPDATE: adding the logs from NextCloud client

```
02-14 16:18:01:239 10228 OCC::PostfixLineEdit::setFullText: "**************/"
02-14 16:18:01:330 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::CheckServerJob created for "**************/" + "status.php" "OCC::OwncloudSetupWizard"
02-14 16:18:02:313 10228 OCC::CheckServerJob::finished: status.php returns:  QMap(("edition", QVariant(QString, ""))("installed", QVariant(bool, true))("maintenance", QVariant(bool, false))("needsDbUpgrade", QVariant(bool, false))("productname", QVariant(QString, "Nextcloud"))("version", QVariant(QString, "14.0.0.0"))("versionstring", QVariant(QString, "14.0.0 alpha")))   QNetworkReply::NetworkError(NoError)  Reply:  QNetworkReplyHttpImpl(0x1875ce88)
02-14 16:18:02:313 10228 OCC::OwncloudWizard::appendToConfigurationLog: Setup-Log:  "<font color=\"green\">Successfully connected to **************/status.php: Nextcloud version 14.0.0 alpha (14.0.0.0)</font><br/><br/>"
02-14 16:18:02:313 10228 OCC::OwncloudSetupWizard::slotOwnCloudFoundAuth: void OCC::OwncloudSetupWizard::slotOwnCloudFoundAuth(const QUrl&, const QVariantMap&)  was redirected to "**************"
02-14 16:18:02:313 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::DetermineAuthTypeJob created for "**************" + "" "OCC::OwncloudSetupWizard"
02-14 16:18:03:036 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::slotFinished: void OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::slotFinished() QNetworkReply::NetworkError(AuthenticationRequiredError) "Host requires authentication" QVariant(int, 401)
02-14 16:18:03:038 10228 OCC::DetermineAuthTypeJob::finished: virtual bool OCC::DetermineAuthTypeJob::finished() ""
02-14 16:18:03:046 10228 OCC::OwncloudWizard::slotCurrentPageChanged: Current Wizard page changed to  1
02-14 16:18:07:099 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 98 s)
02-14 16:18:07:099 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:18:07:099 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
02-14 16:18:09:907 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::JsonApiJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications" "OCC::ServerNotificationHandler"
02-14 16:18:09:907 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::JsonApiJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications" "OCC::ServerNotificationHandler"
02-14 16:18:21:945 10228 OCC::OwncloudSetupWizard::slotConnectToOCUrl: Connect to url:  "**************/"
02-14 16:18:21:945 10228 OCC::OwncloudWizard::appendToConfigurationLog: Setup-Log:  "Trying to connect to Nextcloud at **************/..."
02-14 16:18:21:946 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "**************" + "/" "OCC::OwncloudSetupWizard"
02-14 16:18:25:056 10228 OCC::ConnectionValidator::checkAuthentication: # Check whether authenticated propfind works.
02-14 16:18:25:058 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::ConnectionValidator"
02-14 16:18:37:106 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 128 s)
02-14 16:18:37:106 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:18:37:106 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
02-14 16:18:57:052 10228 OCC::ConnectionValidator::checkAuthentication: # Check whether authenticated propfind works.
02-14 16:18:57:054 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::ConnectionValidator"
02-14 16:19:07:097 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 158 s)
02-14 16:19:07:098 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:19:07:100 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
02-14 16:19:29:054 10228 OCC::ConnectionValidator::checkAuthentication: # Check whether authenticated propfind works.
02-14 16:19:29:056 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::ConnectionValidator"
02-14 16:19:37:097 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 188 s)
02-14 16:19:37:097 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:19:37:097 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
02-14 16:20:01:061 10228 OCC::ConnectionValidator::checkAuthentication: # Check whether authenticated propfind works.
02-14 16:20:01:063 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::ConnectionValidator"
02-14 16:20:07:102 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 218 s)
02-14 16:20:07:102 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:20:07:102 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
02-14 16:20:25:033 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::slotFinished: void OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::slotFinished() QNetworkReply::NetworkError(RemoteHostClosedError) "Connection closed" QVariant(Invalid)
02-14 16:20:25:033 10228 OCC::PropfindJob::finished: PROPFIND request *not* successful, http result code is 0 ""
02-14 16:20:33:051 10228 OCC::ConnectionValidator::checkAuthentication: # Check whether authenticated propfind works.
02-14 16:20:33:052 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::ConnectionValidator"
02-14 16:20:37:106 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 248 s)
02-14 16:20:37:106 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:20:37:106 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
02-14 16:21:05:052 10228 OCC::ConnectionValidator::checkAuthentication: # Check whether authenticated propfind works.
02-14 16:21:05:054 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::PropfindJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::ConnectionValidator"
02-14 16:21:07:108 10228 OCC::Folder::slotRunEtagJob: * Trying to check "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" for changes via ETag check. (time since last sync: 278 s)
02-14 16:21:07:108 10228 OCC::FolderMan::slotRunOneEtagJob: Scheduling "http://**************/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/userM/" to check remote ETag
02-14 16:21:07:108 10228 OCC::AbstractNetworkJob::start: !!! OCC::RequestEtagJob created for "http://**************/nextcloud" + "/" "OCC::Folder"
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the ELB a static DNS and connected the NextCLoud desktop client using it, and it connected